# Not able to send Images via Telegram Bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

When I give the command, it just doesn't respond. All my other commands are working fine. I am using `pytelegrambotapi`.

My code-

```
import telebot
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
    
#This is my image link
IMAGE_LINK = "https://pixabay.com/images/id-1127657/"
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['image'])
def image(message):
    response = requests.get(IMAGE_LINK)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    #send the photo
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img)
```

Comment: I think that you are sending an html, instead of a photo, given the link that you are passing. You just also catch any Exception that send_photo could trigger, and see what is the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image url is not correct, it goes to a page with other elements along with the image itself.
The correct url for your image is:
`https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/08/11/49/text-1127657_960_720.jpg`

Also you can pass this link to `send_photo` directly, that way Telegram itself will download and send the photo from the url:

```py
IMAGE_LINK = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/08/11/49/text-1127657_960_720.jpg"


@bot.message_handler(commands=['image'])
def image(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, IMAGE_LINK)
```

Comment: Hey can you tell what should I type in the Requirements file in order to deploy this code to Heroku?

Comment: Hey. Create another question for that for others to initiate as well.